# Twice linear kata on codewars Python

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization

I am solving 'Twice linear' kata on Codewars

It goes so:

> Consider a sequence u where u is defined as follows:

> The number u(0) = 1 is the first one in u.
> For each x in u, then y = 2 * x + 1 and z = 3 * x + 1 must be in u too.
> There are no other numbers in u.

> Ex: u = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 13, 15, 19, 21, 22, 27, ...]

> 1 gives 3 and 4, then 3 gives 7 and 10, 4 gives 9 and 13, then 7 gives 15 and 22 and so on...

> Task:

> Given parameter n the function dbl_linear (or dblLinear...) returns the element u(n) of the ordered (with <) sequence u (so, there are no duplicates).

> Example:

> dbl_linear(10) should return 22

I made a solution

```
def dbl_linear(n):
    u_list= [1]
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        u_list.append(u_list[i] * 2 + 1)
        u_list.append(u_list[i] * 3 + 1)
        u_list= sorted(set(u_list))
    return u_list[n]
```

it works, but when it goes to 6 figure numbers time runs out

how can i optimize this solution?

if sorting is out of loop its making wrong numbers after like 200 so it probably beeds to be in
And its still runs out of time

Comment: Sorting looks like it could be done after the for loop

Comment: Not recommended using the constructor `list` as a variable.

Comment: @Sayse made it 


`def dbl_linear(n):
    u_list = [1]
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        u_list.append(u_list[i] * 2 + 1) if (u_list[i] * 2 + 1) not in u_list else None
        u_list.append(u_list[i] * 3 + 1) if (u_list[i] * 3 + 1) not in u_list else None
    u_list = sorted(u_list)
    return u_list[n]`

but now its making wrong numbers after like 200, had same mistake earlyer so made sorting in loop

Comment: @HMH1013 yeah sorry, im learning so allowing myself this type of mistakes, but trying to not have them

Comment: @Sayse and even with sorting out of loop it times out

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74728327/edit) button to update your question